# Multipart getCount returns 2

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trygin to fetch the html source of an email message so i can parse it.
For some reason content.getCount() returns 2
and sometime the content.getBodyPart(i) is actually a nested Multipart object
How do I distinguish between the elements returned by content.getBodyPart(i)
Is this the correct way to fetch the HTML Source?

```
ParsedEmailData procesMultiPart(Multipart content){
    for (int i = 0; i < content.getCount(); i++) {
       BodyPart bodyPart = content.getBodyPart(i);
       Object body = bodyPart.getContent();

if(body instanceof Multipart) {
                  return procesMultiPart((Multipart) body);
                }
if (body instanceof String) {
                return  parsedEmailData = parseEmailBody((String) body);
            }

}
```

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [sample code for finding the main body part of a message](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#mainbody).

Comment: Did you find for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46963241/tortoise-git-get-a-branch-to-new-folder? I suspect the branch name was mispelled somehow

Comment: yes, branch name was wrong, thank you!

Comment: Bill, it dowsnt help since if you look at the exmokae